# Swift: Can't center UIView in Superview with NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

i'm trying to center a view in the parent view but its not centering as expected. Here is my code an a screenshot of the result.

```
emptyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(emptyView)
let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: emptyView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: emptyView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
self.view.addConstraints([centerXConstraint])
self.view.addConstraints([centerYConstraint])
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: `view.addConstraints`?

Comment: Sesquatch the app crashes with: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'

Comment: Where are you writing this code for setting the constraint? This exception means the view is not layout completely and outlets are not set, so you can't apply constraints to them.

Comment: I guess this should be the order:
`emptyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
`view.addSubview(emptyView)`
`view.addConstraints()`

Comment: As @PGDev, suggested, it means your `emptyView` is probably not added.

Comment: I changed the order like @PGDev suggested and it no longer crashes with view.addConstraints. But it's still not centered! Its in the exact same position as the screenshot

Comment: i'm doing everything in viewDidLoad

Comment: also i'm getting this message (don't know if it's related): [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var emptyView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.emptyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let centerXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: emptyView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let centerYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: emptyView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: emptyView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: emptyView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

        self.view.addConstraints([centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

If you are using label or button or any other view that have intrinsic size, there is no need for height and width constraints

ViewController Interface :

[image]

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
emptyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: emptyView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: emptyView.frame.size.width)
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: emptyView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: emptyView.frame.size.height)
var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:[superview]-(<=1)-[label]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX,
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["superview":view, "label": emptyView])

view.addConstraints(constraints)

// Center vertically
constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "H:[superview]-(<=1)-[label]",
        options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterY,
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["superview":view, "label": emptyView])

view.addConstraints(constraints)
view.addConstraints([ widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
```